# button submits email, onclick call invoke function, redirects to a index page and display message

Tags: html, onclick

How can I display a message on the redirected page after submit a form?
I have a form on my page that after submitting the form it redirects to the index.html. After redirecting I have a div with a message that is set to display:none. What I'm trying to do is to set to display:block the div for a couple seconds then set the display back to none. Here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="index.html">
<button onclick="emailSubmit()" class="sub-button" type="submit" value="Send Message" style="margin-bottom: -35px;">Send Message</button>
```

```
<script>
    function emailSubmit() {
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display = "block"; }, 500);
      setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display = "none"; }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cold You please share Your code? How does your html file Look like?
Where Do You keep Your message?

As far You only hidden and show dom element. It is Look like the div is empty.

Comment: This is the div that I I want to show then hide ```<div id="confirmation">
                <h2>Your message was received. Thank you!</h2>
              </div>```